# Can you "wrap" the stock camera's functionality on a droid phone?

Tags: android, camera

My company has a need to print a timestamp on images taken on a droid.  Another developer mentioned that we could wrap the entire functionality of the stock camera, then once a photo is taken, embed the timestamp on it. Can this be done, and if so, how simple/complex would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. Definitely *way* simpler then writing a camera app from scratch.
Here is a short overview to give you a few keywords:

You need to fire a `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent,
this launches the devices camera app and prompts the user to take a picture *(stock app or not doesn't even matter)*. When the picture is taken it will return to your app¹. At this point you'll get a file URI of the taken image that points to a  JPEG usually.

Once you have that, load the image via the [`BitmapFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) into a `Bitmap` object and edit it by using a `Canvas`. You can use [`Canvas.drawText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to draw the text. Then store it where you need it, send it off the device or do whatever you want with it. And that's all the magic.

¹ *[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222151624/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/10/take-picture-in-android-with.html) is a small example how to do that, found via google, there are plenty more out there*